# Access auto declared array

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list, auto

```
auto messwerte2 = { 3.5, 7.3, 4.9, 8.3, 4.4, 5.3, 3.8, 7.5 };
```

Which possibilities exist to access a single value explicitly of this array-like looking structure which as I was informed is actually a  std::initializer_list ?

Comment: I don't know how your loop looks like, and you don't show it, but chances are very much that if you read up on "arrays" you probably will stumble across the right `[]` syntax... and "loop" implies you iterate over individual elements (which implies that it demonstrates how to access a single one...)

Comment: Why is my question on -4? I had a problem, that came probably from a misunderstanding and confusing an array with a different structure of c++ language. How could I fix this question to be "better"? I mean, I received an answer that was directly focused to clarify my misunderstanding, if somebody else has the same problem this thread should help him, as it helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which possibilities exist to access a single value explicitly of this array?

It's not an array, but is deduced to a [`std::initializer_list<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) which can be accessed through an iterator or a range based loop:

```
#include <iostream>

auto messwerte2 = { 3.5, 7.3, 4.9, 8.3, 4.4, 5.3, 3.8, 7.5 };

int main() {

    for(auto x : messwerte2) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa1a9a8868f8fd3e)

To make it an *array* use an explicit array declaration:

```
double messwerte2[] = { 3.5, 7.3, 4.9, 8.3, 4.4, 5.3, 3.8, 7.5 };
```

Comment: The OP knows they can use a ranged based for loop.  They want to know how to get just a single value from a specific position.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Yeah I just noticed that.

Comment: Seems like because an initializer_list cant be used like an array, so seems like it is not possible. Thank you.

Comment: @baxbear Yes. I've added a link to the reference additionally.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto messwerte2 = { 3.5, 7.3, 4.9, 8.3, 4.4, 5.3, 3.8, 7.5 };
```

doesn't declare an array. It declares a [`std::initializer_list<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

To declare an array, use:

```
double messwerte2[] = { 3.5, 7.3, 4.9, 8.3, 4.4, 5.3, 3.8, 7.5 };
```

Then you can use the regular array indexing syntax.